# Feed file outside of public_html

Tags: php, file, download, readfile, public-html

I am having trouble uploading a file to the user from outside of "public_html" which is the folder that everyone has access to thru http. Ex. www.website.com/ everyhting after the / is public_html. I'm sure you all know what I'm referring to.

So I have this script that *should* read a file (sample.pdf) from (server perspective) /images/protected/ but PHP won't find my file. Am I doing this wrong?

```
<?php
$file = '/images/protected/sample.pdf';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
} else {
    echo "404 - FILE NOT FOUND!<br />\n";
    echo "File: $file";
}
?>
```

Every time I execute this script I get the `404 - FILE NOT FOUND!<br />\n` instead of a file download.

Comment: Are you really sure that that's the correct path? It seems odd that a directory called "images" would be in the root.

Comment: Does the httpd process have rights to see or read that file?

Comment: He is probably listing the absolute web path, not the absolute system path.

Comment: @Akke can you login to that box and cd to the "images" directory and show us the output of `pwd`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to supply the absolute system path. Currently, you're requesting a file at `/images/...`, rather than `/var/www/hosts/whateverdomain/images/...`.

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/protected/sample.pdf';
```

If your file is really located at `/images/protected/`, make sure that you have sufficient permissions to read that file.

Comment: and remember it's the user the webserver runs as that needs access rights.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I am on shared hosting so the right "root" path for my website was /home/me/